# How to update different columns based on value of one column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am working with SQL Server 2008. I have 2 tables

**Indicator**

```
Id   |   Region
```

**Indicator12**

```
Id   |   Name  | South America |North America
```

Now I need to update South America (SA), North America (NA) columns if a particular id in  `Indicator` table is mapped to two regions then both SA and NA columns should be marked as `YES` else if it is mapped to only one region then respective columns in `Indicator12` should be marked as `YES`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are after -

```
update Indicator12
set [South America] = case when Indicator.Region = 'SA'
                           then 'YES'
                           else Indicator12.[South America]
                      end,
    [North America] = case when Indicator.Region = 'NA'
                           then 'YES'
                           else Indicator12.[North America]
                      end           
from Indicator12
join Indicator
    on (Indicator12.Id = Indicator.Id)
```